# How do I center the input in div

Tags: html, css, centering

http://jsfiddle.net/4konLwjp/15/
I need center the input in div,
The input always float right.
Is there any way to do it?
HTML:

```html
<div id="siteInfo">
   <input value="Some Button" \>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
#siteInfo {
  padding: 5%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
  text-align : center;
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
input {
  margin: 0 auto;
padding:5%;
width: 300px;
display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: the reason why input cann't center in your siteInfo div is that you set the input a `padding: 5%`, and the input is not a  border-box, it's a content-box , content-box only contains real content when  caclcute width of itself ,so you should change to the border-box, which contains not only real content, but padding、 border

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your code ,you can just add `box-sizing: border-box;` in your `input` style ,like this:

```css
input {
  margin: 0 auto;
padding:5%;
box-sizing: border-box; // add this line
width: 300px;
display: inline-block;
}
```

try it